# MATLAB simplified loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Okay, so i'm struggling with this one. The code below works to how i need it to, however, i'm sure it could be shorter and simpler. I am aware that i could possibly use a for loop in order to make it shorter i just don't know how, could anyone point me in the right direction in doing this. Thanks :)

*if it's not clear form the code what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to convolve separate signals and room impulse responses together using a different process other than the convolution function*

```
close all;
clear all;

[x Fs] = wavread('bass.wav');
[x2] = wavread('drums.wav');
[x3] = wavread('bongo.wav');
[x4] = wavread('shaker.wav');
[x5] = wavread('gtr.wav');

hrir = wavread('HRIR_RR.wav');
hrir2 = wavread('HRIR_RL.wav');
hrir3 = wavread('HRIR_FR.wav');
hrir4 = wavread('HRIR_FL.wav');
hrir5 = wavread('HRIR_C.wav');

hrir_L = hrir(:,1);
hrir_R = hrir(:,2);

hrir_L2 = hrir2(:,1);
hrir_R2 = hrir2(:,2);

hrir_L3 = hrir3(:,1);
hrir_R3 = hrir3(:,2);

hrir_L4 = hrir4(:,1);
hrir_R4 = hrir4(:,2);

hrir_L5 = hrir5(:,1);
hrir_R5 = hrir5(:,2);

L = length(x) + length(hrir) -1; % Output data length
X = fft([x ; zeros(length(hrir_L),1)]);
HL = fft([hrir_L ; zeros(length(x),1)]);
HR = fft([hrir_R ; zeros(length(x),1)]);

L2 = length(x2) + length(hrir2) -1; % Output data length
X2 = fft([x2 ; zeros(length(hrir_L2),1)]);
HL2 = fft([hrir_L2 ; zeros(length(x2),1)]);
HR2 = fft([hrir_R2 ; zeros(length(x2),1)]);

L3 = length(x3) + length(hrir3) -1; % Output data length
X3 = fft([x3 ; zeros(length(hrir_L3),1)]);
HL3 = fft([hrir_L3 ; zeros(length(x3),1)]);
HR3 = fft([hrir_R3 ; zeros(length(x3),1)]);

L4 = length(x4) + length(hrir4) -1; % Output data length
X4 = fft([x4 ; zeros(length(hrir_L4),1)]);
HL4 = fft([hrir_L4 ; zeros(length(x4),1)]);
HR4 = fft([hrir_R4 ; zeros(length(x4),1)]);

L5 = length(x5) + length(hrir5) -1; % Output data length
X5 = fft([x5 ; zeros(length(hrir_L5),1)]);
HL5 = fft([hrir_L5 ; zeros(length(x5),1)]);
HR5 = fft([hrir_R5 ; zeros(length(x5),1)]);

out_L = zeros(L,1); % output buffer
out_R = zeros(L,2);

out_L2 = zeros(L2,1); % output buffer
out_R2 = zeros(L2,2);

out_L3 = zeros(L3,1); % output buffer
out_R3 = zeros(L3,2);

out_L4 = zeros(L4,1); % output buffer
out_R4 = zeros(L4,2);

out_L5 = zeros(L5,1); % output buffer
out_R5 = zeros(L5,2);


out_L = ifft(X .* HL); % multiplication of fft results & ifft
out_R = ifft(X .* HR);

out_L2 = ifft(X2 .* HL2); % multiplication of fft results & ifft
out_R2 = ifft(X2 .* HR2);

out_L3 = ifft(X3 .* HL3); % multiplication of fft results & ifft
out_R3 = ifft(X3 .* HR3);

out_L4 = ifft(X4 .* HL4); % multiplication of fft results & ifft
out_R4 = ifft(X4 .* HR4);

out_L5 = ifft(X5 .* HL5); % multiplication of fft results & ifft
out_R5 = ifft(X5 .* HR5);

out_L = out_L + out_L2 + out_L3 + out_L4 + out_L5;
out_R = out_R + out_R2 + out_R3 + out_R4 + out_R5;

out = [out_L out_R];

sound(out, Fs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using cell arrays. These are general containers for all types of data:

```
fn = {'a.wav','b.wav','c.wav'}

for i=1:length(fn)
  h{i} = wavread(fn{i})

  hrir_L{i} = h{i}(:,1);
  hrir_R{i} = h{i}(:,2);

  ....

end
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a treat. Not entirely experienced with MATLAB but this has helped me a bunch. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Better to ask a question than get stuck with ugly copy/paste code forever...